# Why grails doesn't find enum constructor when I run app in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, enums, gsp

I have a custom tag which uses enum in it's source code. 
When I run application from IntelliJ Idea, or from console (with grails run-app), application
works fine, but in the case I deploy it as a war-file in the Tomcat I get an exception like that:

```
    org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: 
    Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag 
    : tried to access method 
    app.MyEnum.(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;)V from class
    app.MyEnum.Enum$1
```

The enum looks like that:

```
public enum MyEnum {

    VALUE1("EnumValue1") {
        void printNumber(int number) {
          println (number)
        }
    },
    VALUE2("EnumValue2") {
        void printNumber(int number) {
          println (number * 2)
        }
    }

    static final MyEnum DEFAULT = VALUE1

    final String name

    private MyEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    abstract void printNumber(int number) {
    }

}
```

UPD: Everything works fine if I make MyEnum's constructor public, but it seems awkward and I still don't get why it doesn't work without public modifier.

Comment: Ever able to call any private constructor??

Comment: I don't call enum's constructor explicitly. Exception happens on the initialization phase, as I understand.

Comment: Why do you need to have private constructor in Enum ? You can't use it  explicitly even if it public...

Comment: Everything works fine if I make MyEnum's constructor public? really??